# Open GL ES vs Metal Core Image for CIContext

Tags: swift, opengl-es, core-image, metal

I have some custom filters written in `Open GL Shading Language` with `CIKernel` coupled with some built in filters. When I create a `CIContext` would it be faster to use an automatic context (I'm guessing not but could be wrong), with Metal, or with Open GL ES? I am using it for both images and videos, so would one be faster with a certain type?

I just need it be fast and perform well (everyone's dream right ).

**Update:** On a side note, I am using `UIImage`, converting that to `CIImage`, and then returning a `UIImage` when adding filters to my image. Will just using `Metal` or `Open GL ES` for a `CIContext` help at all or do I need to start using `MTLTexture` and things like that to gain any benefit?

Comment: Very good question. (1) Are you targeting macOS or iOS? (2) If iOS, which version? [I try to target the bottom line, so I'm thinking iOS 9+.] (3) Are you chaining both CIKernel and "canned" filters, or something else? (4) The tough one - specifics. Are you seeing something specific to a device, iOS version, or filter chain that is causing you an issue? Can you get into specifics? [I work with images only and find the combination of custom CIKernel/GLKView works extremely well *on* iOS devices but lags on the simulator.]

Comment: @dfd 1) iOS; 2) iOS 10.0; 3) Umm.. what is a "canned" filter? Is it like a 3rd party framework like `GPUImage`? 4) Actually, it is pretty fast on iOS devices, and I'm also seeing that it lags very badly on the simulator (almost takes a minute on my Mac whereas it is very fast on my iPad). For the most part, it should be fast but I want to make sure it's as fast as it can be. If you have any more questions feel free to ask :). Thank you soo much for your help

Comment: (1) Same here. (2) I target iOS 9 and above, since you can write custom filters. (3) Apologies, I meant filters delivered by Apple. :-) Last year they focused much more on Metal. (4) It's not uncommon IMHO for the simulator to *severely* lag when using CoreImage. No concrete proof, but I believe it's how the simulator doesn't have a GPU and how it must "cycle" between your Mac's CPU and it's GPU. It not at all uncommon for me to try a filter like CIGaussianBlur - one of the most basic ones - and wait 15 or more seconds for something, only to find it instantaneous on a physical device.

Comment: @dfd 3) In that case yes I am using custom filters along with filters delivered by apple :)!

Comment: I used to use a combination (or chain) of two custom GLSL filters (one Color, one Warp) along with a mask filter. It's now 100% custom (a general one). Truth be told, I don't see much difference in either the simulator (where it lags a bit) or my test devices. I was fishing for details. :-) Also, keep in mind that I work with images only. As for video? My favorite resource **by far** is www.flexmonkey.com. Recently I put a comment on a question here with a few links. Search there for both video and Metal - he has several great examples in his GitHub.

Comment: His iBook called *CoreImage for Swift* is my best resource for everything. He's moved on some since last March, but it's up to date and he's a great Swift coder to boot.

Comment: @dfd Ok sounds good :) I'll have to look at it when I gg a chance

Comment: Did you find out which is faster, and by roughly what percentage?

Comment: Hey Harish! Do you have any updates on this subject?